# How do I export/import Business Units & Security Roles in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: deployment, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

Pretty simple thought considering we're rolling out according to normal development paradigms (Development environment, then pushing to Production after QA).

I'm not able to find anywhere on the web describing how to export all the Business Units our teams have built into our development environment and then re-import. Also, Security Roles we've created underneath specific Business Units aren't available to do an "Add Existing" to a Solution.

Seems like this should be something simple. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just gone through this myself. Sorry man, there is no way to include business units into a solution. We had to manually create all the BU's again in our Production environment.  You can deploy Root level security roles. I decided to create Root level security roles since I can add those into a solution. It makes for a less organized security role setup, but I know I'm deploying tested security roles. I created a naming convention that helped organize them better since I went this direction.